# Как подключить CSS и картинки к HTTP-серверу на python?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, http, веб-сервер

У меня есть HTTP-сервер на Python:

```py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time

hostName = "localhost"
serverPort = 9090

print('I am server.')
file = open(input('Name: '), 'r')
filer = file.read()
file.close()

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(filer, "cp1251"))

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print(f"Server started at http://{hostName}:{serverPort}")

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        webServer.server_close()
```

Когда я подключаюсь к `http://localhost:9090` я могу видеть только HTML без CSS. Картинки, которые были привязаны к HTML-странице тоже не отображаются.

**UPD**: Как мне отправить CSS-файл, также как и HTML-файл?

Пробовал:

```py
self.send_header("Content-type", "text/css")
self.end_headers()
self.wfile.write(bytes(css_file, "cp1251"))
```

Но то что я отправляю как CSS, записывается в html-файл

Comment: для этого нужно, что бы ваш сервер отдавал кроме html-содержимого так же и файлы. В том числе картинки и css

Comment: @cauf cпасибо, но как это сделать с css? Я пробовал self.send_header("Content-type", "text/css"), но это не работало. Когда я смотрел исходный код в браузере, отосланный мною css, печатался в html-файл.

Comment: @dimimir у вас же только один файл отправляется. Только HTML. Почитайте про Flask или Django, или же напишите парсер запрашиваемого в запросе URL.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский спасибо. Я неправильно сформулировал свой вопрос. Я хотел спросить: как мне отправить CSS-файл?

Comment: @dimimir я уже сказал: чтобы отправить какой-либо файл, нужно сначала понять, какой файл запрашивается клиентом. Вот URL, где это реализовано: https://gist.github.com/mdonkers/63e115cc0c79b4f6b8b3a6b797e485c7.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский так я знаю какие файлы запрашивает клиент. Я не знаю, как их ему отправить